# Role of Audience in poetry

Tags: poetry

**what's the exact role that audience play or expected to play in field of poetry?**

This question arises because it's been often said that poems do not have a particular definition, every poet define it uniquely indeed. Therefore it's prominent to be known whether a poet is free to express his feelings to the fullest without considering the likes of audience or is it the audience who shape the poems?
I believe poems are not poems until and unless accepted and applauded by the readers and listeners.
What is the reality?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there isn't an answer to this question: it depends on your ideas about literary theory and the role of the reader or audience in creating any text. As well, different poets have different views.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Vimath. I'm not very sure whether this is on-topic here, and would suggest trying the Literature SE. Their rules are not very clear on literary theory or "meta" discussion and Stack Exchange does not encourage reposts, so I encourage you to start by going to Literature SE's meta site and asking if your question would be accepted there. If it would, we can try to transfer it.